# Sql stored procedure taking lot of time for execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing a big issue, the below stored procedure taking lot of time for execution. Please help me to find issues with following stored procedure   .

We need to insert bulk subscriber list from excel in to database. But only 60 subscribers are getting inserted in to db in one minute.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
 USE [SMS]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_ProcessFile]    Script Date: 01/30/2015 12:56:59 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO



    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ProcessFile] 


        @JobCode varchar(25)
        WITH RECOMPILE
    AS
    declare
    @jobCode1 Varchar(50),
    @count int,@Code varchar(50),@Name [varchar](50),@Date Datetime,@Status int,
    @i int,@EUCount int,@SubCount int,
    @Add1 nvarchar(3000) ,
    @Add2 nvarchar(500) ,
    @Add3 nvarchar(500) 
    ,@refdate  [varchar](50) ,
    @reference  [varchar](50) ,
        @Joined [varchar](50),
        @Joinmonth [nvarchar](50),
        @Activated [varchar](50),
        @ActivMonth [nvarchar](50),
        @Center [varchar](50) ,
        @Region [varchar](50) ,
        @Area [varchar](50) ,
        @Modem [varchar](50) ,
        @Adomstatus [varchar](50)
    ,   @AddCode [varchar](50)
    set @i = 1
        Set @jobCode1 =@JobCode
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        Set @Status =    (Select Distinct(status) from TSMST1005 where Jobcode = @jobCode1)

    if (@Status = 0)
        begin
            Select '1' as res
        end
        else
        begin

        CREATE TABLE #tblSMS(pID int identity(1,1),     
        [Reference] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Date] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Subname] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [Address1] [nvarchar](3000) NULL,
        [Address2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
        [Address3] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
        [Joined] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Joinmonth] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Activated] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [ActivMonth] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Center] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Region] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Area] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Modem] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Adomstatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [RefDate] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
        insert into #tblSMS

        SELECT  Reference,[Date],
        Code,Subname ,Address1 ,Address2 ,Address3 ,
        Joined  , Joinmonth ,Activated, ActivMonth ,
        Center,Region,Area,Modem,Adomstatus ,refdate   FROM TSMST1005 where jobcode = @jobCode1 and Status =1

        WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tblSMS)
            BEGIN
            SELECT 
        @Code =Code,
        @Name = Subname,
        @Date =[Date],
    @Add1 =Address1 ,
    @Add2 =Address2 ,
    @Add3= Address3,

    @reference  =Reference ,
        @Joined = Joined,
        @Joinmonth =Joinmonth,
        @Activated =Activated,
        @ActivMonth =ActivMonth,
        @Center = Center,
        @Region = Region,
        @Area= Area,
        @Modem = Modem ,
        @Adomstatus =Adomstatus,
    @refdate = RefDate 

            From #tblSMS where pID = @i 

        Insert into TCMST5001 (CompanyCode  , Address1,Address2 ,Address3 ,CreatedDate ,Status) values('001',@Add1 ,@Add2,@Add3,GETDATE(),1)
        Set @count = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        Set @AddCode = 'ADD' + Cast(@count As Varchar(10))


        Update TCMST5001 Set Code =@AddCode Where AddressID =@count 
        Set @EUCount = (Select COUNT(*) from TCCOM0005 where EnterpriseUnitCode = @Center)
        if (@EUCount = 0)
        Begin
        Insert into TCCOM0005(AddressCode,CompanyCode,EnterpriseUnitCode,EnterpriseUnitName,Status) values(@count ,'001',@Center,@Center ,1)
        END
      Set @SubCount = (Select COUNT(*) from TSMST1001 where Subscriber = @Code) 
      if (@SubCount  =0)
      begin
      Insert into TSMST1001(ActivationDate ,refdate , Address ,AlternateName ,Area ,Region ,Subscriber,Name ,date ,CreatedDate ,EnterpriseUnit ,Status) 

      values(@Activated,@refdate ,@count ,@Name,@Area,@Region,@Code,@Name ,@Joined ,GETDATE(),@Center,@Adomstatus)
      end
      Insert into TSMST1003 (Device ,CreatedDate ,Subscriber,StartDate) values 


(@Modem,GETDATE(),@Code,@Activated)

            SET @i = @i + 1
            Update TSMST1005 Set Status = 0 where Jobcode = @jobCode1 
            Select '3' as res
        END
        END
        Drop table #tblSMS 
        end
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Don't just use `VARCHAR(n)` for **everything** out of lazyness!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to give you 100% working procedure. However your problem is that you are inserting records row by row. Instead of doing that you need to insert records in BULK. That would work A LOT faster. There is rewritten procedure. You still need to rewrite 2 inserts by the same logic. Of course there could be bugs as it is fully untested. Anyway, here we are:

```
    USE [SMS]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_ProcessFile]    Script Date: 01/30/2015 12:56:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ProcessFile] @JobCode VARCHAR(25)
    WITH RECOMPILE
AS

    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SET @Status = ( SELECT TOP 1 status 
                        FROM    TSMST1005
                        WHERE   Jobcode = @jobCode
                      )

        IF ( @Status = 0 )
            BEGIN
                SELECT  '1' AS res
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN

                CREATE TABLE #tblSMS
                    (
                      pID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
                      [Reference] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Date] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL ,
                      [Code] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Subname] [VARCHAR](500) NULL ,
                      [Address1] [NVARCHAR](3000) NULL ,
                      [Address2] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL ,
                      [Address3] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL ,
                      [Joined] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Joinmonth] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Activated] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [ActivMonth] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Center] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Region] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Area] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Modem] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [Adomstatus] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
                      [RefDate] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
                    )
                INSERT  INTO #tblSMS
                        SELECT  Reference ,
                                [Date] ,
                                Code ,
                                Subname ,
                                Address1 ,
                                Address2 ,
                                Address3 ,
                                Joined ,
                                Joinmonth ,
                                Activated ,
                                ActivMonth ,
                                Center ,
                                Region ,
                                Area ,
                                Modem ,
                                Adomstatus ,
                                RefDate
                        FROM    TSMST1005
                        WHERE   jobcode = @jobCode1
                                AND Status = 1

                WHILE @i <= ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
                              FROM      #tblSMS
                            )
                    BEGIN

                        DECLARE @minPK INT;
                        SELECT @minPK = MAX(AddressID ) FROM TCMST5001; -- I believe that it is identity column. If not change it to the proper one
                        INSERT  INTO TCMST5001
                                ( CompanyCode ,
                                  Address1 ,
                                  Address2 ,
                                  Address3 ,
                                  CreatedDate ,
                                  Status
                                )
                       SELECT '001', Address1, Address2, Address3, GETDATE(), 1 FROM #tblSMS;

                        SET @AddCode = 'ADD' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10))


                        UPDATE  TCMST5001
                        SET     Code = 'ADD' + CAST(AddressID AS VARCHAR(10))
                        WHERE   AddressID > @minPK ;

                        INSERT INTO TCCOM0005
                        SELECT ee.cnt, t.center, t.Center, 1
                        FROM #tblSMS t
                        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM  TCCOM0005 e WHERE e.EnterpriseUnitCode = t.Center) ee
                        WHERE ee.cnt > 0

                        -- THE SAME LOGIC MUST BE DONE WITH THESE 2 INSERTS

                       SET @SubCount = ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
                                          FROM      TSMST1001
                                          WHERE     Subscriber = @Code
                                        ) 
                        IF ( @SubCount = 0 )
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT  INTO TSMST1001
                                        ( ActivationDate ,
                                          refdate ,
                                          Address ,
                                          AlternateName ,
                                          Area ,
                                          Region ,
                                          Subscriber ,
                                          Name ,
                                          date ,
                                          CreatedDate ,
                                          EnterpriseUnit ,
                                          Status
                                        )
                                VALUES  ( @Activated ,
                                          @refdate ,
                                          @count ,
                                          @Name ,
                                          @Area ,
                                          @Region ,
                                          @Code ,
                                          @Name ,
                                          @Joined ,
                                          GETDATE() ,
                                          @Center ,
                                          @Adomstatus
                                        )
                            END
                        INSERT  INTO TSMST1003
                                ( Device ,
                                  CreatedDate ,
                                  Subscriber ,
                                  StartDate
                                )
                        VALUES  ( @Modem ,
                                  GETDATE() ,
                                  @Code ,
                                  @Activated
                                )

                        UPDATE  t
                        FROM TSMST1005 t
                         SET     Status = 0
                        JOIN #tblSMS tmp
                          ON tmp.jobCode1 = t.Jobcode

                        SELECT  '3' AS res
                    END
            END
        DROP TABLE #tblSMS 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

some tips will be. Avoid doing this in every step.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tblSMS
```

instead assign the count value to a local variable, and check the i against the same.

Also you are selecting values from these tables ( TCCOM0005, TSMST1001, TSMST1003 ) frequently , It will be good to check if these tables have proper indexes.